# R markdown keeps losing its working directory

Tags: r, r-markdown, working-directory

I have set the `root.dir` in the settings:

````
```{r setup, include=TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = "E:/something/Lists")
```
````

with `getwd()` I can check that it worked.
On top of that, I have set the working directory to exactly the same path in the RStudio tools.
This works without problems for the code chunks. E.g. I load a table and it appears correctly in the global environment:

````
```{r, include = TRUE, echo = FALSE}
fevofe<-read.table(file = "112_Auswertg.csv", header = T, sep=";", dec=".")
```
````

However, I have some inline code in order to have some numbers generated within my plain text.

```
"All in all we found `r length(fevove[,1])` specimens..."
```

And this inline code does not react to setting the `root.dir`. As soon as I try to run these code bits, R markdown keeps telling me that it hasn't found the object - although it is already in the global environment, because it was loaded in the previous code chunk.
After executing this inline code and the error, I ask R markdown `getwd()` and suddenly it is my Documents folder!
Consequently, when knitting, the process is cancelled, because the object is lost and then I get the Error:

```
Error in eval(parse_only(code), envir=envir) : object 'fevofe' not found calls <Anonymous>... inline_exec -> hook_eval -> withvisible -> eval -> eval
```

Has anybody an idea what causes this stubborn resetting of the working directory?

Any hint is welcome

Comment: Would you make sure the code chunk that makes `fevofe` precedes the inline code chunk?

Comment: Yes, that is introduced earlier.

Answer (score 0):

so this is an interesting case:
The basic problem was a typo: fevofe was in the problematic lines spelled fevove...
Correcting this helped knitr to complete the job.
However, it seems strange enough that this causes R markdown to reset the working directory to something that is not even the standard in the options.
This topic remains interesting...